# split string and store it in another variable in c#

Tags: c#, .net

How to Read character after `'\'`:

```
string PrName = "software\Plan Mobile";
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: from this string "software\Plan Mobile", how do i read the characters after "\" and store them in a different variable using c#

Comment: See my proposal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
char charToFind = '\';
string PrName = "software\Plan Mobile";

int indexOfChar = PrName.IndexOf(charToFind);

if (indexOfChar >= 0)
{
    string result = PrName.Substring(indexOfChar + 1);
}
```

Output: `result = "Plan Mobile"`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not forget `@`:

```
 string PrName = @"software\Plan Mobile";
```

Next, if you want just the tail only (i.e. `"Plan Mobile"`) then `Substring` will do:

```
 // if no '\' found, the entire string will be return
 string tail = PrName.Substring(PrName.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

If you want both (all parts), try `Split`:

```
 // parts[0] == "software"
 // parts[1] == "Plan Mobile"
 string[] parts = PrName.Split('\\');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to split string

```
   string s = "software\Plan Mobile";

   // Split string on '\'.
   string[] words = s.Split('\');

   foreach (string word in words)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(word);
   }
```

**Output:**

```
software
Plan mobile
```